# Выбор цвета фона чётным элементам

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Выбираю чётные строки из таблицы:

```
$("#courses tr:even").css("background-color", "green");
```

И зелёной становится 2 строчка, а 0 строчка, которая состоит из `<th>`, не меняется.

```
<table class="data" id="courses">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Код</th>
            <th>Название</th>
            <th>Ак.ч</th>
            <th>Комплекс</th>
            <th>Цена</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>XML</td>
            <td>XML И XSLT. Современные технологии обработки данных для ВЕБ (<a class="doc" href="#">ссылка</a>)</td>
            <td>32</td>
            <td>Радио</td>
            <td>16 490</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>AJAX</td>
            <td>AJAX. Разработка веб - приложений для Web 2.0 (<a class="doc" href="#">ссылка</a>)</td>
            <td>24</td>
            <td>Бауманский</td>
            <td>14 490</td>
        </tr>           
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

А с чего ей меняться, если вы указываете замену фона только `<tr>`? Укажите также `<th>`.

Comment: Но в html идёт так для первой строки:

<tr>
                    <th>Код</th>
                    <th>Название</th>
                    <th>Ак.ч</th>
                    <th>Комплекс</th>
                    <th>Цена</th>
  </tr>




а в след строчках идут <td>

Comment: Попробуй написать так tr:nth-child(even)

Comment: Всё-равно меняет только те строки, где идут td, а нулевая строка, где th - не меняется. Странно ((

Comment: Поменял <th> на <td>, и тогда строка 0 выделяется !!!
Значит нужно <th> считать отдельно и обрабатывать.

Comment: Решил вот так !!!

$("#courses tr:even").add("#courses th").css("background-color", "green")

Comment: @Владимир а зачем, если не секрет? `.add()` не выглядит как элегантное решение. Более того, не вижу проблем со строкой заголовка [в fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dochvfLy/).

Comment: без .add() он не выделяет строчку 0, которая является чётной.

Я заменил th на td, и тогда моё обычное условие срабатывает на 0 строчку, но с th эта 0 строчка не выделяется.
А с .add() у меня выделилась 0 строчка.

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример выборки всех четных элементов

```
$("table tr:odd")
```

[Посмотрите по селекторам, нормально написано тут](http://www.quizful.net/post/jQuery_selectors)

Ну а так то, в первом комменте написано правильно выборка только по tr а не по th и так как она всегда первая её можно залить по умолчанию.